# Can I extend or hook in to update method of a repository?

Tags: flow-framework

Is there a way in Flow to hook into or extend the update method/function of a repository? I like to create several messages (as objects) if an object changes anyhow.

Currently we use the UnitOfWork in the controller after we give the object to the repository to update. But with that the messaging just works there in that function and not "global" where ever I update that object.

I don't like the idea of putting that in to the setters of that object. That would be nasty code in my opinion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to make `YourRepository` which will be extending `Repository` and implement your `update()` method (or call `parent::update()` and implement rest of your logic). All your repositories should then inherit `YourRepository` class instead of `Repository`.

Create `YourRepository`:

```
use TYPO3\Flow\Annotations as Flow;
use TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Repository;
/**
 * @Flow\Scope("singleton")
 */
class YourRepository extends Repository {
    public function update($object) {
        parent::update($object);
        // your logic
    }
}
```

or copy-paste `update()` method body from `Repository` class and add your logic:

```
public function update($object) {
    if (!is_object($object) || !($object instanceof $this->entityClassName)) {
        $type = (is_object($object) ? get_class($object) : gettype($object));
        throw new \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Exception\IllegalObjectTypeException('The value given to update() was ' . $type . ' , however the ' . get_class($this) . ' can only store ' . $this->entityClassName . ' instances.', 1249479625);
    }

    $this->persistenceManager->update($object);
}
```

Each repository of domain `Model` should now inherits from `YourRepository`:

```
use TYPO3\Flow\Annotations as Flow;
/**
 * @Flow\Scope("singleton")
 */
class ModelRepository extends YourRepository {

}
```

Comment: Super. Helps me a lot. Have a nice week. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should take a look at Flows AOP feature. Under the premise of separation of concerns (SoC) it is not the task of the repository to send out notifications.

Have a look at the docs:
[Aspect Oriented Programming](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/AspectOrientedProgramming.html)